# How to make ScrollViewReader scroll to top of List?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have `List` within a `TabView` and allowing the user to scroll to the top when they double tap a tab. I'm using a `ScrollViewReader` to scroll to a specific anchor. However, it is not fully scrolling to the top of the list because of the navigation title, see the title overlapping the content:

[image]

I'm using the technique from [this blog post](https://designcode.io/swiftui-handbook-tabbar-scroll-to-top) for more context. Below is a working sample:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var _selectedTab: SelectedTab = .one
    @State private var tabbedTwice = false

    var selectedTab: Binding<SelectedTab> {
        Binding(
            get: { _selectedTab },
            set: {
                if $0 == _selectedTab {
                    tabbedTwice = true
                }
                _selectedTab = $0
            }
        )
    }

    enum SelectedTab: String {
        case one
        case two
    }

    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { proxy in
            TabView(selection: selectedTab) {
                NavigationView {
                    List {
                        Section {
                            ForEach(1...50, id: \.self) { index in
                                Text("Item \(index.formatted())")
                            }
                        }
                        .id(SelectedTab.one.rawValue)
                        Section {
                            Text("Section 2")
                        }
                    }
                    .navigationTitle("First")
                }
                .tabItem {
                    Label("One", systemImage: "clock.arrow.circlepath")
                }
                .tag(SelectedTab.one)
                NavigationView {
                    List {
                        Section(header: Text("Header").id(SelectedTab.two.rawValue)) {
                            ForEach(50...100, id: \.self) { index in
                                Text("Item \(index.formatted())")
                            }
                        }
                        Section {
                            Text("Section 2")
                        }
                    }
                    .navigationTitle("Second")
                }
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Two", systemImage: "list.bullet")
                }
                .tag(SelectedTab.two)
            }
            .onChange(of: tabbedTwice) {
                guard $0 else { return }
                withAnimation { proxy.scrollTo(_selectedTab.rawValue, anchor: .top) }
                tabbedTwice = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better place to put the anchor identifier? I tried putting on the first section and also the section header which worked better but still not scrolling to the very top. How can this be achieved?

Comment: what ios are you using? The glitch that you show does not seem to happen on a real device with ios-16.2.

Comment: This issue happens because of a Large title, Even if you don’t use List, Still I didn’t find any solution, did you find  a solution !?

Comment: I am using an `EmptyView` as the first item in the `List` as an anchor, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75076596/swiftui-tabview-run-code-in-subview-after-sequential-taps/75276153#75276153