# SwiftUI TabView react to multiple press on tabitem

Tags: swiftui, tabbar

My goal is to navigate back/scroll up on the content view inside a TabView when the user presses on an active tabItem again. Just like the normal behaviour in the Apple Music app or any other big app.

In order to achieve this I need to react to taps on these tabItem.

No matter how I try to get this nothing works.

My example looks like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedTab = Tab.First

    private enum Tab {
        case First
        case Second
        case Third
    }

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
            Text("First").tabItem {
                Text("First")
                Image(systemName: "globe")
                    .onTapGesture {
                        print("This will never be called")
                    }
            }
            .onTapGesture {
                print("This creates just a tabGesture on the whole view.")
            }
            .tag(Tab.First)
            Text("Second")
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Second", image: "pencil")
                        .onTapGesture {
                            print("Also this does not work")
                        }
                }
                .tag(Tab.Second)

            Text("Third")
                .tabItem {
                    VStack {
                        Text("Third")
                        Image(systemName: "globe")
                    }
                    .onTapGesture {
                        print("Nope")
                    }
                }
                .tag(Tab.Third)
        }
        .onChange(of: selectedTab) { _ in

            print("This only works for the first change.\n"
                + "Not if it gets selected again.")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75076596/swiftui-tabview-run-code-in-subview-after-sequential-taps

Comment: Yes this article did the trick:

https://notificare.com/blog/2022/11/25/a-better-tabview-in-swiftui/

I will answer my own question an reference it as duplicate.