# How to make tab view dismiss view like in SwiftUI like in UIKit

Tags: swiftui, uikit

In UIKit if you have a UITabBarController and you tap a tab it will pop to the previous view controller same as if you tapped back or swiped right.

TabView in SwiftUI seems to be missing this behavior. If you tap a tab after navigation to a new view nothing happens.

Is there a way to have this same tap to dismiss behavior on tabs in SwiftUI as in UIKit?

Here's just a simple SwiftUI TabView demonstrating this with a tab. When you tap the tab after tapping Navigation Link it won't dismiss back to the main view like with UIKit.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            NavigationStack {
                NavigationLink {
                    Text("Detail")
                } label: {
                    Text("Navigation Link")
                }
            }
            .tabItem {
                Label("Tab", systemImage: "globe")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75076596/swiftui-tabview-run-code-in-subview-after-sequential-taps/75276153#75276153